# Can accuracy decrease with training size?

Tags: machine-learning, accuracy

I have a balanced training set; the test set follows the original distribution and is imbalanced. I fit a number of models to the training set, using 5-fold cross-validation. I perform this for 5 seeds, get the prediction of each run (per seed), average the predictions and round it up. I then get the train and test accuracy from here. I do this for different train sets of different sizes, but keep the test set the same every time (n_test=100000). I'm sure the train and test sets don't overlap.

So the seeds don't turn out to be much different from each other; the train and test accuracy are also fairly close. However, though the train and test accuracy increases with training size at first (until n_train=10000), at some point, it starts to dip for some models (SVM-RBF and KNN) (n=13000). This is a binary classification problem by the way.

Is this even possible, or does this mean I have a bug somewhere?

EDIT: I've added a plot of the train accuracy for various models with train size. Apologies for the quality...

[image]

Comment: You mentioned imbalance, describe in more detail.

Comment: Original dataset has a 60-40 imbalance, with a total dataset size of ~250000 corresponding to individuals of difference demographics. The train-test split was stratified based on these demographics (age and gender categories); further, the train set was further subset by (a) making sure n_0_train = n_1_train = n_train/2 and (b) the demographic distribution of n_0_train and n_1_train are the same as n_0_test and n_1_test (stratified sampling).

Comment: Can you check what the accuracies look like throughout time? To answer your question, yes, accuracy can decrease over time if you are overfitting, which is suggestive of your parameters, why are you using so many iterations?

Comment: What do you mean "throughout time"? I use sklearn's built-in functions for the SVM and it gives me just the final results. Do you mean at every step of gradient descent?

Comment: Let's back up. So you keep the test set fixed for all the models ($10^5$ observations) and you built many models using different number of observations for the training set (from somewhere below $10^4$ up to and to more than $1.3\cdot 10^4$ observations)? And your accuracy first increases and then decreases after using $1.3 \cdot 10^4$ observations for the training set *for some models*? Is you training set always balanced in all these models? Are the observations chosen at random for each training set or are you sequentially adding observations based on some ordering?

Comment: I create the training/test sets only once, and the same train/test sets are used for every model. The training set is balanced in terms of the response variable (50-50 split); the test set follows the original distribution of the response (more like 60-40). The training set also follows some extra stratified sampling for each segment--for example, if those with response 0 are 70% "old" and 30% "new" in the full dataset, while those with response 1 are 40% "old" and 60% "new" in the full dataset, then the training set will also follow these 70-30 and 60-40 distributions. (to be cont)

Comment: (cont) I then use the same train/test sets for all the models, which include Logistic Regression, Linear SVM, SVM-RBF, and KNN. I also run the models with 5 different seeds. I then average the predictions and round up the values (>=0.5 average -> 1, < 0.5 -> 0). Then I compare these with the real response and get the accuracy from there.

What I find is that the train and test accuracy increase until n_train=10000, but somehow decreases at n_test=13000, and this only occurs for some models. I was wondering what could have gone wrong.

Comment: You mention in the beginning that you make only the one split for training / testing. So what exactly is `n_train` and `n_test` then? What are you changing with this?

Comment: For example, I am interested in n_train = 10000 and n_test = 100000. So I split it once. After that, I use this same train-test split dataset for different seeds in the SVM. I do the same process for (n_train=13000, n_test=100000), (n_train=4000,n_test=100000) and so on.

Comment: I don't understand, you say you use n_train=10000 and later n_train=4000, so you are using different splits for training data? How do you split this training data then? How do you decide which 10000 training data to use the first time and which 4000 training data to use later?

Comment: Yes, there are different splits. I am looking at how the train and test accuracies would change for different train sizes but the same test set. Here's how the data is split: first, it is split into the test set and the mega-train set. The test set (n=100k) is now fixed. The mega-train set is then subsampled into smaller sample sizes. Although the n_train=10k and n_train=4k train sets could have some intersection, any train set is sure not to intersect with the test set.

Comment: And how do you split / subsample the train set? Are you choosing data points at random or is there some ordering to the split? Do you split them sequentially (based on time or some order)? Also, can you provide one plot of this phenomena, that is train size and accuracy?

Comment: The subsampling is done at random via sklearn's `train_test_split`, and I stratified the split based on some other property of the users (`stratify_by` user age groups). I'll update the post above to include the plot.

Comment: The plots look fine to me, there is some slight dip in accuracy for some models when increasing the sample size but this is negligible (easily attributable to randomness) so I would not worry about this.

Comment: Ah I see. That's good to know then -- I've been looking for bugs and couldn't find anything that would cause this. Thank you!